# Load markers with json

Tags: android, dictionary, cordova

I followed [this link](http://jquery-ui-map.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/load%20JSON%20example.html) in my application. In turn, I get the white spaces in my device and `.Map` is not displayed.

**Code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#map_canvas').gmap().bind('init', function() {
        $.getJSON( 'http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx?latitude=&longitude=', function(data) {
            $.each( data.Status.Shoplist, function(i, m) {
                $('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker', { 'position': new google.maps.LatLng(m.lat, m.lng)} );
            });
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

**json:**

```
{"Status" :{ "Shoplist":[ { "id" : "1", "Name" : "ee", "phone" : "", "fax" : "",   "latitude" : "xxxxxx", "longitude" : "yyyyyyy" } , { "id" : "3", "Name" : "hhh", "phone" : "", "fax" : "",  "latitude" : "xxxx", "longitude" : "yyyyy" } ,..... } ]}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have added any external hosts in your white list in PhoneGap.

In iOS add hosts to the ExternalHosts key in the PhoneGap.plist as per the FAQ on this page: http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/41631150/PhoneGap%20for%20iOS%20FAQ

in Android add hosts to the phonegap.xml file in /res/xml in your project. The format is different than iOS. Here is an example phonegap.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<phonegap>
    <access origin="http://127.0.0.1*"/>
    <access origin="http://*.phonegap.com"/>
    <log level="DEBUG"/>
</phonegap>
```

Wildcards are allowed as in the example above.

Make sure to add any external hosts your scripts might be trying to call (with Google maps that can be varied and many). While you are trying to get it to work you could always just add `*` to allow all external hosts.

Answer (score 0):

Since your json doesn't have lat or lng attributes you should change the code in the addMarker method to

`new google.maps.LatLng(m.latitude, m.longitude)`